# Align android text and images in listview to be the same

Tags: android, android-layout, alignment

I need some help with alignment of custom list view with image and text.

I'm trying with this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:text="TextView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And I thought that weight is keeping the ratio of element, not the content of the element, but apparently it takes care about things inside the text view, so my list looks messy.

How to align it to be the same, no matter how long the text is in text view?

[image: My Crazy alignment]

So the green line should be straight vertical line, no matter of text on right hand side.

Tnx

Comment: Have you tried using a "simple" text view and adding the image as it's leftmost compound drawable? The bounds of the drawable can (and must, unless you go with intrinsic size) be set to your required 50dp. The text view should fill the parent in that case and center itself with the gravity ofc.

Comment: I'm using custom adapter on several places so I did not try to put everything in simple text view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `android:layout_weight`.

This will align you images since you define the width.

If you want to align the text too, remove `android:gravity` or set it to left.

You can add `android:marginRight` to the imageView for better readability.

Comment: Tnx, I used some of your suggestions, and I've fixed textview size in order to keep it the same no matter to the text lenght.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, your layout should be this:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

The `android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"` defines the leftmost compound drawable, and it will align nicely.

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

use

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
```

in your textView. it will give fixed size to all your elements. here, the size shared by the weight param is variable as it depends on the amount of text.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:text="TextView" />
</LinearLayout>
```